# How can I find the PPI of an iOS device programmatically without using hardcoded values?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

For years, my company has been maintaining a large switch statement mapping devices to specific PPIs.  This is painful to maintain especially when new devices like the iPad Pro are released.  Is there any way to get this number programmatically, rather than using hardcoded values?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the PPI directly, because you would need to know the physical size of the screen to do it which can't be accessed programatically.

Perhaps if you explain the problem you are solving with the large switch statement, someone can help you find a more general approach